The page isn’t redirecting properly how to solve
I want to restricts both user home and admin dashboard when only login then open otherwise redirect to login or admin login page.
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import { NextRequest } from 'next/server'
// This function can be marked `async` if using `await` inside
export function middleware(request) {
  
  const token= request.cookies.get("token")?.value;
  const admintoken= request.cookies.get("admintoken")?.value;

  const notLoginInUserNotAccessPathwithAdmin =
  request.nextUrl.pathname==="/login"||
  request.nextUrl.pathname=="/signup" ;
  
  
  const notLoginAdminNotAccessPathAdmin=
  request.nextUrl.pathname=="/admin";

     if(notLoginInUserNotAccessPathwithAdmin){
      if(token){
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/home', request.url))
      }
     }else{
      if(!token){
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/login', request.url))
      }
     }
     
     if(notLoginAdminNotAccessPathAdmin){
      if(admintoken){
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/dashboard', request.url))
     }
     }else{
      if(!admintoken){
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/login', request.url))
      }
     }
}
 
// See "Matching Paths" below to learn more
export const config = {
  matcher: ['/users/:path*','/dashboard/:path*','/login','/signup','/admin','/home/:path*'],
}

I want to restricts both user home and admin dashboard when only login then open otherwise redirect to login or admin login page .

This is one way that I can think of doing that. I have modified couple of codes to make it more readable and easily changeable. Feel free to let me know if you need further modifications.
    import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
    import { NextRequest } from 'next/server'

    export function middleware(request) {
      const userToken = request.cookies.get("token")?.value;
      const adminToken = request.cookies.get("admintoken")?.value;

      const userPaths = ['/home', '/profile', '/user-settings']; // user-specific paths
      const adminPaths = ['/dashboard', '/admin-settings']; // admin-specific paths

      const isUserPath = userPaths.some(path => request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith(path));
      const isAdminPath = adminPaths.some(path => request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith(path));

  // Redirect to login if user tries to access a protected user path without a user token
      if (isUserPath && !userToken) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/login', request.url));
      }

  // Redirect to admin login if someone tries to access a protected admin path without an admin token
      if (isAdminPath && !adminToken) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/admin-login', request.url));
      }

  // If a logged-in user tries to access the login/signup page, redirect them to their home
      if (request.nextUrl.pathname === '/login' || request.nextUrl.pathname === '/signup') {
        if (userToken) {
          return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/home', request.url));
        }
      }

  // If a logged-in admin tries to access the admin login page, redirect them to the dashboard
      if (request.nextUrl.pathname === '/admin-login') {
        if (adminToken) {
          return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/dashboard', request.url));
        }
      }

      return NextResponse.next(); // continue with the request as normal if no redirect is required
    }

    export const config = {
      matcher: ['/home/:path*', '/profile', '/user-settings', '/dashboard/:path*', '/admin-settings', '/login', '/signup', '/admin-login'],
    };


